# Cancel Telnet prompt WITHOUT closing connection?

Tags: linux, telnet

I opened a Telnet connection from a Linux machine, and hit `Ctrl + ]` to bring up the `telnet>` prompt. **How do I drop out of this prompt and go back to my session without closing the Telnet connection?**

There weren't any breadcrumbs in `help`, and pressing `Ctrl + ]` again, or `Ctrl + C` just prints the escaped char, while `Ctrl + D` closes the connection. None of these are desired.

It must be simple, I just can't find it anywhere - everything Google gives me is about closing/quitting the session.

Comment: If you're down voting, please leave a quick comment to explain why so I can improve the question, or ask better in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hit enter without entering anything after the `telnet>` prompt and you're back to the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If a connection with a host is already established in telnet try `Ctrl` + `]`. If you are already in `telnet>` try `\q`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but \q aliases to quit, which closes the session. I don't want to close the session...

Comment: Ugh, I completely miss read this entire question i apologize! I Guess I still hadn't had my morning coffee yet :). Glad you worked it out.